# How to send http delete request in ReactJS when clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express

I'm trying to send a delete http request but it does not work. Delete request should be send when clicking a button. Please help.

```js
const ondeletehandle = async() => {
  const response = await fetch('/api/notebook/' + notebooks._id, {
    method: 'DELETE'

  })
  const json = await response.json()

  if (response.ok) {
    dispatch({
      type: 'DELETE_NOTEBOOK',
      payload: json
    })
    console.log(notebooks)
  }
  if (!response.ok) {
    console.log("error")
  }
}
```

i tried looking up for delete header but that didn't work

Comment: are you seeing any error ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  In what way is your code not working as expected?  Please elaborate on the specific problem you are observing and what [debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193) you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.